# How do I select data form multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am currently trying to make a retweet system for my site but the problem I'm having is that I have the posts table separate from the retweets table and I can't find an easy way to merge them together.

These are my table structures

```
retweets {
    retweet_id, 
    retweet_post_id, 
    retweet_user_id, 
    retweet_time
}
posts {
    post_id, 
    post_type, 
    post_user_id, 
    post_data, 
    post_private, 
    post_poster_ip, 
    post_time
}
```

So what I am trying to get both those tables and have them ordered by the most recent (so if a retweet was the most recent it would display first in the row). How could I do this? Or would it be more efficient to have it all done inside one table?

Comment: You use JOINs in your SQL query

Comment: Try it with one table, then once you have that working try to do it with two

Answer (score 0):

You need to use INNER JOIN, joining the tables by the appropriate foreign key:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    posts
INNER JOIN
    retweets
ON
    posts.post_id=retweets.retweet_post_id
```

Read here about the JOINs if necessary:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

> Or would it be more efficient to have it all done inside one table?

Read about the [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to learn, how to split the tables correctly. So you can avoid [anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies) and decrease the amount of duplicated information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` to combine the sets (based off of matching `retweet_id` and `post_id`), and use `ORDER BY` to sort based off of `retweet_time`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM retweets
JOIN posts 
ON retweets.retweet_id=posts.post_id
ORDER BY retweet_time DESC
```